# amcharts' stockChart mouse move listener

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I'm trying to add a listener to amCharts' stockChart but can't find where.

According to [the docs of chartCursor](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ChartCursor) you can set `changed` event on `chartCursor` however `chartCursor` does not exist on stockChart, only regular charts according to [the docs of the StockChart](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart).
As far as I can see the only semi-relevant settings is [chartCursorSettings](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ChartCursorSettings) but it does not allow setting any listeners.

How can I catch mouse move/changed event over amCharts' amStockChart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `changed` event can be caught at the [panel](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel#changed) level:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "panels": [{
    // ...
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "changed",
      "method": function(e) {
        console.log('changed event fired')
      }
    }],
  }],
  // ...
});
```

Demo below:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
  "theme": "light",

  "categoryAxesSettings": {
    "minPeriod": "mm"
  },

  "dataSets": [{
    "fieldMappings": [{
      "fromField": "value",
      "toField": "value"
    }],

    "dataProvider": generateChartData(),
    "categoryField": "date"
  }],

  "panels": [{
    "stockGraphs": [{
      "valueField": "value",
      "type": "smoothedLine"
    }],
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "changed",
      "method": function(e) {
        console.log('changed event fired')
      }
    }],
  }],

  "chartCursorSettings": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true
  }
});


function generateChartData() {
  var chartData = [];
  var firstDate = new Date( 2012, 0, 1 );
  firstDate.setDate( firstDate.getDate() - 1000 );
  firstDate.setHours( 0, 0, 0, 0 );

  for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
    var newDate = new Date( firstDate );
    newDate.setHours( 0, i, 0, 0 );

    var a = Math.round( Math.random() * ( 40 + i ) ) + 100 + i;

    chartData.push( {
      date: newDate,
      value: a
    } );
  }
  return chartData;
}
```

```css
 #chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: blessings be upon you!

Comment: btw, as I see you work for amCharts - do let them know that it's really hard to understand that from their documentation

Comment: Sure. I'll pass that along.